# Comparing 2 Big-O expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to solve the following problem:

"Al and Bob are arguing about their algorithms. Al claims his $O(n*logn)-$
$time$ $method$ is always faster than Bob’s $O(n^2)-$ $time$ $method$. To settle the issue, they perform a set of experiments. To Al’s dismay, they find that if $n < 100$, the $O(n^2)-$ $time$ $algorithm$ runs faster, and only when $n >= 100$ is the $O(n*logn)-$ $time$ one better. Explain how this is possible."

Watching the Big-O definition I can see that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if there are constants $C$ and $k$ such that

$abs(f(x)) <= C*abs(g(x))$ whenever $x > k$

Also, I know that $O(n^2)$ comes from a polynomial of degree 2 that might have a coefficient and other terms of lower degree.

I do not find how to relate this facts in order to make a conclusion although I suspect that constants $C$ and $k$ could play an important role in such a conclusion.

I will very much appreciate any clue so I can get a better idea about how to formulate an answer.

Comment: Choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1\cdot 100\cdot\log 100 = c_2\cdot 100^2$.

Comment: I am actually curious about where this comes from -- there seems to me that the statement of the question actually reveals either a misunderstanding or an abuse of notation about the $O(\cdot)$. Technically, given the statement Bob's algorithm could have time complexity $O(1)$ and run in constant time -- this would *still* be a $O(n^2)$-time algorithm. And a $O(2^{2^n})$-time algorithm, for that matter.

Comment: Also, even besides that the asymptotic analysis is,unless specified otherwise, *worst-case*. That is, Bob's algorithm could very well be $O(\sqrt{n})$-time on average-time (or even faster), and only take qudratic time on very adversarial and contrived inputs; while Alice's algorithm could be $\Theta(n\log n)$ on average, and outperform Bob's only on these adversarial (and very unlikely) inputs, which would never show up during the "set of experiments."

Comment: If one is looking at small-$n$ cases, as opposed to asymptotic behaviour, even an $O(1)$ could be slower than, say, $O(n^2)$. The big-O tells you how the computation time scales with the number of operations as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @ClementC. I don't think it reveals any such misunderstanding or abuse. There is an obvious intended solution (to someone who knows how to solve this easily). Other solutions exist, and presumably they would be accepted as off-the-beaten-path correct answers. Nowhere does practicality or "average case running time" on "inputs" of the *completely unspecified* algorithm enter into the question.

Comment: Hello Clement C. This problem is from a homework assignment of a computer science class.

Comment: @MattSamuel I understand the intended solution; Im merely saying that the phrasing of the question (and the intended answer) are not consistent with the actual definition of the big-O notation. That is, they assume it as characterization of the running time (i.e., like a $\Theta()$, roughly) while it's just an asymptotic *upper bound*. Saying that $f(n)$ is say $O(n^2)$ does *not* mean that $f(n)$ is asymptotically scaling like $g(n)$, up to constants (even though it's used like this in many situations). It only means that $f(n)$ scales *at most* like $g(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to state that a problem scales as $O(f(n))$ does NOT mean that the problem scales **exactly** as $f(n)$. It describes the limiting behavior as $n \to \infty$. For example, given any specific value of $n$, some $O(n^2)$ algorithms will be faster than some $O(nlog(n))$ algorithms. But, for specific $O(n^2)$ and $O(nlog(n))$ algorithms, if you let $n$ get big enough then the former will always be larger than the latter.